Practice to use memcpy or strncpy to copies the string into memory
I am writing a piece of simple practice to compare the usage of between memcpy or strncpy. I see that I can do this string copy using either of these two functions:
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );

and
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );

Simple practice
    char src[] = "Hello World";
    char dst[20];

    strncpy(dst, src, 5);
    printf("%zu-", strlen(dst));

    memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst));
    printf("%zu-", strlen(dst));

    strncpy(dst, src, 5);
    printf("%zu", strlen(dst));

The actually output
5-11-11

How can I understand what the behave differently with respect?
In general, how can I find out relative bytes of memory block different copied by using  memcpy or strncpy?

Note that because src is is longer than 5 bytes, the '\0' is not copied to dst with strncpy. From cppreference: if count is reached before the entire array src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated.

With memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst)); you will go out of bounds of src. All out of bounds access leads to undefined behavior. Use MIN(strlen(src) + 1, sizeof(dst)). But remember, just like for strncpy the destination might not be null-terminated after that.

memcpy and strncpy are very different things. They can be (mis)used to do string copy but that's not what they are intended for. Use strcpy to copy oridinary C style strings.

For fun try to change your code to char dst[20] = "abcdefghijklmn";

More info of why strncpy should be avoided here: Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?

    strncpy(dst, src, 5);
    printf("%zu-", strlen(dst));

When the count is exhausted before a null character is found in the source, strncpy does not write a terminating null to the destination. Then dst may not be null-terminated, in which case the behavior of strlen is not defined. However, the fact “5” is printed is consistent with dst happening to contain a zero in dst[5].
    memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst));
    printf("%zu-", strlen(dst));

Your src has only 12 bytes, while sizeof(dst) is 20, so this memcpy attempts to read bytes from beyond src. Again, the behavior is not defined. It likely copied into dst the 11 bytes of “Hello World”, the following null byte, and then eight bytes from whatever happened to be in memory after src.
    strncpy(dst, src, 5);
    printf("%zu", strlen(dst));

At this point, dst likely contains the data described above, the 11 bytes of “Hello World” and the following null byte, and that causes strlen to return 11.

strncpy doesn't add a NUL if there's not enough space. Since strlen requires a NUL-terminated string, the first use of strlen results in undefined behaviour.
Properly using strncpy requires ensuring a terminating NUL, which you can do using the following:
strncpy(dst, src, 5);  // At most `sizeof(dst)-1`
dst[5] = 0;
printf("%zu\n", strlen(dst));

stpncpy is similar to strncpy, except it returns a pointer to the position after the last non-NUL character it wrote. So could also use the following:
*stpncpy(dst, src, 5) = 0;
printf("%zu\n", strlen(dst));


There's a second problem. Your memcpy attempts to copy 20 bytes, but the object from which you are copying only occupies 12. So that's undefined behaviour too. Don't copy more bytes than you have!

Good improvement. Minor: "Properly using strncpy requires ensuring a terminating NUL, ..." is more like "Properly using strlen requires ensuring a terminating NUL ..." as strncpy() does not need to work with nor produce strings.  Of course,  dst[5] = 0; insures that dst[] contains a string, yet that is for strlen(dst) (and many other str...()) benefit.

@ikegami Deleted my comments as your edit has fixed the problem :-)
